# ArcMap replica error number and description list

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, replication, error-000582

We have a replica between our sql server geoDB and another sql server geoDB. It is a one-way replica and our geoDB is the child. Recently an error occurs (error 000582). I searched for the cause of the error and got from ESRI forum which said:

> This error can occur if one or more of the feature classes and datasets are not versioned or don't have GlobalIDs."

Details check: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52003.

> The feature classes and datasets are not versioned or don't have GlobalIDs,

May I confirm is the issue from the parent side?

Now the user want to see the official support for description of the error, but I failed to find it.

I want to check whether there is a source which list all the replica errors and the cause for them. I am using ArcSDE 10.1.

Comment: What are you attempting to do when the error occurs? Synchronize? Set up your replica activity log and see what object the tool fails on: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000wv000000

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, the error occur when we are synchronize the replica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice offered from the posting that you cited is:

> Try adding the data you want to replicate to ArcMap, and then using
>   the Create Replica command off the Distributed Geodatabase toolbar
>   instead of the GP tool.  The error messages it provides are more
>   complete than when using the GP tool.

I recommend following that advice and, if the resultant error message does not provide easier to interpret information, then at least you have another symptom to research/ask about.

This is the [documentation for 000582 : Error occurred during execution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00vp00000015000582).